# Post Message/Picture on friends wall in Facebook using FBGraph API (iOS7 and iOS6)

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I'm developing app in which I will retrieve the Facebook user ID from my account. Now I want to post message or image on my friends wall directly using my app. I'm using fbgraph API.

I want this feature to work in iOS7 and iOS6. Is it possible?
I have already tried this code but I can't receive any response.

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[user_id]/feed"  andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test wall post"forKey:@"message"]
```

andHttpMethod:

```
@"POST"andDelegate:self];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do it ..

**By Graph APi**
Write it in your class :

> - (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action {
>     // we defer request for permission to post to the moment of post, then we check for the permission
>     //publish_actions
>     if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
>         // if we don't already have the permission, then we request it now
>         [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
>                                               defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
>                                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
>                                                 if (!error) {
>                                                     action();
>                                                 }
>                                                 //For this example, ignore errors (such as if user cancels).
>                                             }];
>     } else {
>         action();
>     } }

and in your share_btn method :

> [self performPublishAction:^{
>
> ```
>             NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                                            @"My Name", @"name",
>                                            url, @"link",
>                                            @"I am a Good guy", @"caption",
>                                            @"I love Arsenal", @"description",
>                                            @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Arsenal_FC.svg", @"picture"],
>                                            nil];
>
>             [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"
>                                   completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result,
> ```
>
> NSError *error)
>                   {
>                                             if (error) {
>                                                 NSLog(@"Error on publishing story: %@", error);
>                                             } else {
>                                                 NSLog(@"Published story successfully");
>                                             }
>                   }];
>
> ```
>         }];
> ```

provide a link to picture, note that this Graph API dont show modal Pop up for Sharing.

**Via SLCompose**

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

> __weak SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
>
> ```
> [controller setInitialText:[SocialIntegrationNative appShareText]];
>
> [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"]];
>
> __block SLComposeViewController *shareController = controller;
>
> [controller setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
>
>     switch (result) {
>         case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
>
>             break;
>         case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
>
>             break;
>
>         default:
>             break;
>     }
>
>
> }];
> ```